# wsdl2java using axis2 error - "More than one part for message modifyReservationRequest "

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I'm using axis2 to generate java code.(i used both sync and async mode to generate code, no luck)

Command -

```
./wsdl2java.sh -a -ap  -uri http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AAResWebServices?wsdl -o /Users/mk/Office
```

error -

```
Retrieving schema at 'AA_CommonTypes.xsd', relative to wsdl'.
Retrieving schema at 'AA_CommonTypes.xsd', relative to wsdl'.
[ERROR] More than one part for message modifyReservationRequest
org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder$WSDLProcessingException: More than one part for message modifyReservationRequest

Caused by: org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder$WSDLProcessingException: More than one part for message modifyReservationRequest
```

you find link in above mentioned command, Please advice if you can.

Xsds -

```
http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/AA_CommonTypes.xsd
http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/OTA_SimpleTypes.xsd
http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/OTA_CommonTypes.xsd
http://airarabia.isaaviations.com/webservices/services/OTA_AirCommonTypes.xsd
```

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.006" id="AASchema.CommonTypes">
<xs:attributeGroup name="AAPayloadAttributes">
<xs:attribute name="UserId" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="ChannelId" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
<xs:attributeGroup ref="AACommonPayloadAttributes"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>
<xs:attributeGroup name="AACommonPayloadAttributes">
<xs:attribute name="MessageId" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="TimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="Version" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="TransactionIdentifier" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="EchoToken" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
<xs:attribute name="SequenceNmbr" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="PrimaryLangID" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
</xs:attributeGroup>
<xs:complexType name="AAStatusErrorsAndWarnings">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="ErrorCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ErrorText" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="warningMessage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="success" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:attributeGroup name="AACurrencyAmountGroup">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Amount.</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:attribute name="Amount" type="xs:decimal" use="optional">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
The code specifying a monetary unit. Use ISO 4217, three alpha code.
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="CurrencyCode" type="xs:string" use="optional">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
The code specifying a monetary unit. Use ISO 4217, three alpha code.
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="DecimalPlaces" type="xs:integer" use="optional">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
Indicates the number of decimal places for a particular currency. This is equivalent to the ISO 4217 standard "minor unit". Typically used when the amount provided includes the minor unit of currency without a decimal point (e.g., USD 8500 needs DecimalPlaces="2" to represent $85).
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
</xs:attributeGroup>
<xs:simpleType name="ETicketStatusUpdateType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="CHECKEDIN"/>
<xs:enumeration value="BOARDED"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:complexType name="PFSPax">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="arrivalAirport" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="cabinClassCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="entryStatus" type="EntryStatus" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="isParent" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="paxType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="pnr" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="eTicketNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="infant" type="PFSPax" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="PFSFlight">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="departureDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="flightNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="fromAirport" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="EntryStatus">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:enumeration value="GO_SHORE"/>
<xs:enumeration value="NO_SHORE"/>
<xs:enumeration value="NO_REC"/>
<xs:enumeration value="OFF_LD"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: show us your ``AA_CommonTypes.xsd``.

Comment: @JannisM https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Dd_lr8QBqec3ZOeXJKT3NMOHc

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Dd_lr8QBqec3ZOeXJKT3NMOHc

let us know if you need any other information

Comment: Edit it in your question pls.

Comment: Done Jannis. Please check and advice

Comment: You should add the content off theese files to the question, this is needed for future visitors which maybe have the same problem and then the files are maybe not available anymore.

Comment: Done. let me know if you have clue

Comment: http://www.isaaviation.com/thinair/webservices/api/airinventory
@MukeshKumar Im looking for XSD of same namespace
such as `AA_CommonTypes.xsd`